# Set interval Slider with Random starting <div>, How to traverse through all <divs>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Jsonp request returning block of html like this

```
<div id="slider_wrapper" style="">
    <div style="xxx" ><section style="xx">xx</section></div>
    <div style="xxx" ><section style="xx">xx</section></div>
    <div style="xxx" ><section style="xx">xx</section></div>
    <div style="xxx" ><section style="xx">xx</section></div>
    ...
    ... 
</div>
```

here number of inner  depends on DB rows.

After this, I am sliding the content using the set interval as fallowing

Note: Here i want to start the sliding from random position , not always from 0th position
here id = random number

```
setInterval(function() {  
                     $('#slider_wrapper > div:eq('+id+')')
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo('#slider_wrapper');
            },  5000);
```

Above solution is working fine , Problem is It repeats same contents and will not start from position 0 once it reaches last div  ,

For example :
Total number of divs: 5
if random number is 2
It starts from 2,3,4,2,3,4,....not 2,3,4,0,1,

How to slide from first once it reaches end regardless of starting div?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
setInterval(function() {  

   if(! $("#slider_wrapper:has(div:eq('+id+'))") )
        {
           id = 0 ;
        }

                     $('#slider_wrapper > div:eq('+id+')')
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo('#slider_wrapper');
            },  5000);
```

Comment: Where to check this condition ?

Comment: No @Aritra . That condition will never become true.

Comment: What makes you say that ? I have a second suggestion anyway.... If the divs are coming from database, then simply add an id to each of the divs. Then use this : `if ($("#slider_wrapper").find("#id").length > 0) `